# ERRO AO FAZER GIT PUSH --SET-UPSTREAM ORIGIN MASTER

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando fazer um `git push`, mas sempre surge este erro:

```
$ git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master


dell latitude@DESKTOP-KU6NT53 MINGW64 ~/Downloads/hellospringboot (master)
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
To https://github.com/LealVinicius/arqdesint.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/LealVinicius/arqdesint.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: `Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally`
O que o erro acima está dizendo é que você não tem no seu repositório local, as últimas alterações que foram recebidas no seu repositório remoto no GitHub. Geralmente, basta executar `git pull origin master` antes de fazer o `push` novamente.

Answer (score 0):

O aviso que o comando `git push` está emitindo sinaliza que a sua árvore está dessincronizada em relação ao *branch master* do GitHub. Neste caso você tem duas opções:

1. ignorar as diferenças e sobreescrever o *branch* master que está no GitHub fazendo um *push* forçado;
2. fazer um *merge* dos dois *branches* (o seu master local e o do GitHub) e fazer novamente um `git push`.

A primeira opção é a mais simples e mais arriscada. Ela irá ignorar os commits do *branch master* do GitHub e o sobreescreverá com o seu *branch* local. Para isso basta acrescentar o argumento `--force`:

```
$ git push --set-upstream --force origin master
```

Caso o servidor continue recusando o seu *push*, verifique se a opção para recusar *forced pushes* está habilitada na configuração do seu repositório GitHub e desabilite-a.

A segunda opção é um pouco mais complicada mas é mais segura. Ela deve ser executada em alguns passos:

1. fazer *checkout* do *branch master* local: `git checkout master`
2. certificar que você tem a cópia exata do *branch master* do GitHub com o comando `git fetch origin`;
3. fazer um merge to seu *branch master* com o *branch* do GitHub: `git merge origin/master`;
4. caso haja pendências como conflitos, por exemplo, resolva-as e faça *commit* (`git mergetool`?);
5. finalmente faça o *push*: `git push --set-upstream origin master`

Ah, você pode juntar os passos 2 e 3 em apenas um se usar o comando *pull*: `git pull origin`